# sql mysql Max()

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I need to display a query with MAX statement but I don't know how.
I will explain with 2 simples tables to understand better.

- 1 table **family**

```
family
------
id int(1) - PK
name varchar(255)
```

- 1 table **person**

```
person
------
id int(1) - PK
FK_id_family - FK family(id)
first_name varchar(255)
age int(1)
```

Content of tables

```
family
------
1 - DUPONT
2 - MARTIN
3 - PETIT
4 - DUPRES
```

```
person
------
1 - 1 - Jean - 70 (family DUPONT)
2 - 1 - Jeannette - 65 (family DUPONT)
3 - 1 - Pierre - 35 (family DUPONT)
4 - 1 - Nicolas - 29 (family DUPONT)
5 - 2 - Andre - 69 (family MARTIN)
6 - 2 - Ginette - 58 (family MARTIN)
7 - 2 - Benjamin - 25 (family MARTIN)
```

I need to have a query that display family.name, person.first_name, person.age WHERE the person is the older in the family and also the family name where there are not person linked to.
The result will be this one.

```
DUPONT - Jean - 70
MARTIN - Andre - 69
PETIT - NULL - NULL
DUPRES - NULL - NULL
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the maximum `age` by grouping `FK_id_family` in person table and then join it with `family`. This way, you will get `name` and with highest `age` together.

Now, you need to make join with `person` table to get `first_name` column.
I have not tested below sql. But, I hope, this will give you expected output.

```
select 
f.name,
pr.first_name,
p.age
from family f 
inner join
(select FK_id_family as id, MAX(age) as age from person group by FK_id_family) p on p.id=f.id
inner join 
person pr on pr.FK_id_family=p.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery with group by for get the older of each family and the left join  with others table for get the resul

```
  select  family.name, person.age, person.first_name
  from family
  left join (
        select FK_id_family, max(age)  as older
    from person
    group by  FK_id_family 
    ) t  on family.id = t.FK_id_family
  left join person  on family.id = person.FK_id_family and t.older = person.age
```

Comment: could this be more efficient one @scaisEdge
SELECT  family.name, t.age, t.first_name
  FROM family
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT first_name,age,FK_id_family FROM person GROUP BY person.FK_id_family HAVING MAX(age)) t  ON family.id = t.FK_id_family

Comment: @PraveenE  for performance evaluation .. must see the explain plan .. normally the having work on filtering the result and are less efficent that  join  .. but  .. you must see the plan and and how the index are using (if thera are index)  also IN clause is not efficent as  join .. too